# How to load different component if route has params using VueJS Router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I'm looking for a proper way to load a different VueJS component if there are any props included in a route.

For example, if I go to

> /users

I get the users list page and if I'd go to

> /users/1

I would go to user profile page.

I've been trying to add another route as a child with parameters but it wouldn't seem to help:

```
{
            path: "users",
            name: "users",
            component: UsersList,
            children: [
                {
                    path: "users/:userId",
                    name: "User Profile",
                    component: UserProfile,
                },
            ]
},
```

I am pushing the user profile route from a method like this:

```
this.$router.push({ path: 'users', name: 'User Profile', query: { userId: row.id }})
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simple. This is what you need to do:

```
{
    path: "users",
    name: "users",
    // IMPORTANT - UserParent contains `<router-view></router-view>`
    component: UserParent,
    children: [
        {
            // IMPORTANT - NEEDS TO BE BLANK
            path: "",
            name: "user-list",
            component: UserList,
        },

        {
            path: ":userId",
            name: "user-profile",
            component: UserProfile,
        }
    ]
}
```

Here routes will be concatenated to form final routes.

Comment: Thanks, this works, but the URL when accessing user-profile route is getting changed from `/users` to `/?userId=9` and I'm looking to keep the `/users`.

Any way to achieve that?

Comment: @butaminas, you are using query params in your routing like this: `query: { userId: row.id }`. Don't do that. Use: `this.$router.push({ path: 'users', name: 'User Profile', params: { userId: row.id }}`. You should use `params` and not `query`.

Comment: Thanks! This was the main problem!
Also, just so I wouldn't need to use a parent component, I moved `user-profile` route out of the child and changed the path to `users/:userID` to achieve same result.

Comment: @butaminas, While it will work, but you should use it when you want to activate both the views at the same time. With your routing configuration, both UserList, as well as UserProfile components, will be active. That is the impression it creates. Of course, there are ways. But is that what you really need? Prefer clean routing structure. It helps in a long run.

Comment: in this particular case, `user-profile` route is used as an alternative to a modal. After you finish editing a user, you get back to the `user-list` route and there is no other ways to reach the `user-profile` route other then going to `user-list` route first.

I do agree though that it makes more sense to have `user-profile` route as a child route in a long run, but if it's a very small app, creating a parent component is as unclean as having an extra route. Will experiment both cases though.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! I would to know why it is important to have the first child's path to be empty/blank